# Using variable as attribute but with a space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

Given I have object with a name property which is, say: 'Woodcutters Hut'. If I try to assign this to a button attribute:

```
$('#possible_constructions').append("<button name=" + object.name + ">" + object.name + "</button>")
```

The buttons writing is correctly the entire 'Woodcutters Hut' however the name attribute only consists of the first word 'Woodcutters'. and hut is displayed outside like so:

```
<button name="Woodcutters" hut>Woodcutters Hut</button>
```

Anyway to ensure the attribute is assigned properly?

Comment: replace space with a underscore `name="Woodcutters_hut"` using `$('#possible_constructions').append("<button name=" + object.name.replace(/ /g, "_")+ ">" + object.name + "</button>")`

Comment: @Sharky I see this would work, but then the buttons text has the underscore along with it - anyway to avoid that?

Comment: @user3317592 Why do the `name` and text need to be the same? Why does the button need a `name` in the first place?

Comment: refresh page to see my updated comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let jQuery handle the name value for you. Don't build a string.

```
$("<button></button>", { 
    name: object.name, 
    text: object.name
}).appendTo("#possible_constructions");
```

Though it's important to note that "Woodcutters Hut" isn't an appropriate name. You shouldn't be using spaces in your name values. You should consider instead consider reshaping that value into something more appropriate - perhaps by replacing non-alphanumeric characters with underscores:

```
object.name.replace(/[^\w]/g, "_");
```

This would convert "Woodcutters Hut" into "Woodcutters_Hut".

Answer (score 0):

try this , if it works

```
  $('#possible_constructions').append("<button name='" + object.name + "'>" + object.name + "</button>")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Volker E.: But it does provide an answer! Look for the single ticks in the `<button name=''>`.

Comment: actually i recommend the working solution, i my point was to solve prolem not getting votes and repu so i said "try this" if this doesnt works we will try other things,but i was sure about that so didnt commented instead posted it as an answer
@volker